# furnace heating air inlet and outlet

Tags: heating

I saw a diagram as below:
[image]

I am confused with inlet air and outlet air. I think heating air should be all output from the vent port, why still need some inlet air? If I clogged the inlet air,what's the negative impact to my heating system?

Answer (score 1):

The furnace needs combustion air to allow the fuel in the furnace and water heater to burn efficiently. Too little supply air can produce a lot of adverse effects.

Comment: I think the air should be input from the big tube into furnace and output from outlets in house. the input tube port is opened at outside (a big fan at outside also). for the ports in the house, why they still feed air to furnace?

Comment: your comment;
"I think the air should be input from the big tube into furnace and output from outlets in house. the input tube port is opened at outside (a big fan at outside also). for the ports in the house, why they still feed air to furnace"  makes no sense. A better explanation of what you mean is necessary and I mean no disrespect to you.